# python append a frame at the end of tif file

Tags: python, image, append, frame, tiff

Dear stackoverflow community, does anyone know how to append a new frame at the end of a tif file with python. This could be easily done with MATLAB, but I havn't find any way in python yet. I tried the first tried,tiffffile, it can write multiframe stacks but won't append frames to existing file, always overide it. Then I tried PIL image.save, it works for adding one frame, but gives errors when adding another frame. It looks like there is no tag_v2 information in the saved tif files, and the tag_v2.get(IMAGEWIDTH) gives NONE. Then it gives a series of errors. Can anyone point me a new direction? Great thanks

Comment: Try the [append](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/master/tifffile/tifffile.py#L788) parameter with tifffile's `imwrite` or `TiffFile`. See the tests for [examples](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/master/tests/test_tifffile.py#L6879-L6923)

Comment: both of them work. Thanks a lot. I didn't know they have "append" parameters, it is not documented in the TiffFile webpage. Thanks a lot